# Reset root password on Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, root

I’ve been trying to wrap my head around this for a while. So I somehow managed to goof up my `root` password and now I can’t access my remote server, when I login. I however, have `sudo` access through another user using SSH.

Therefore, I have root privileges, just that I can't seem to access the root login.  So how can I reset the `root` password using `root` privileges from another user? Is it even possible?

EDIT: Could it be possible that my /etc/sudoers file is conflicting? Because each time I log in, it says ACCESS DENIED. I have both "root" and my other username in there.

Comment: Yes, if you are a sudo user (ALL privilege) then you can try `sudo -i` and enter normal user password. It will go to root prompt from there you can change root password.

Comment: @max unfortunately that didn't work. When I try to SSH using root, it tells me it can't authenticate it. Any ideas?

Comment: Two things:   ssh user@ip and then sudo passwd root {enter new password twice}  and retry if this  fails,  did ssh root@ip EVER work ? if not its likely that  the remote system is /has been hardened and disallows ANY ssh root@ip actions I personally have my  laptop set in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Become root:
`sudo su -`

then:
`passwd`

Also, if you want to ssh as root, check your `sshd_config` for `PermitRootLogin`.
This is a security risk though, so it's better to login as a normal user and use sudo.

Comment: PermitRootLogin was set to NO. Maybe that's why I wasn't able to log in?

Comment: That didn't work. I tried resetting the password using sudo passwd root and even though it updated successfully, it still says ACCESS DENIED. What could be the issue?

Comment: After changing `PermitRootLogin=YES` did you restart the SSH service?